# Updates in external js file is not reflecting as event fires

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I am using an external js file which is linked in **Master .aspx** file as below.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="questionsContent/questions.js"></script>

     </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

.js file

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".answerlink").click(function (e) {

    alert("1");
    var str = e.currentTarget.id;

    var res = str.replace("ansBtn", "#footerDiv");
    var id = str.replace("ansBtn", "");

    // updates buttons' ID

    $('#btnSubmit').attr('id', 'btnSubmit' + id);
    $('#btnCancel').attr('id', 'btnCancel' + id);


    $(".txtEditorDiv").appendTo($(res));
    $(".txtEditorDiv").show('slow');
    alert('Event fired by' + str);

})


});
```

Control on which jquery is fired, is created dynamically in child page..

Yesterday I made some changes in js file, which is not relecting as event fies.

For ex: there are 2 alerts in js function, in which alert("1") which is added yesterday is never fired but 2nd alert is fired since its there from start.

Am I missing something?

Comment: `..ipt" src="questionsContent/questions.js">..` so, just curious, does the js can be accessed from the browser? (just hoping it's not a path issue)

Comment: yes. its accessible from browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your browser having the updated js file. Clear the cache if needed. Also you can use browser's developers option for debugging.